# How do I match strings that start with 4 digits but ignore those with a colon in front of it

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match all substrings that start with 4 digits except for those that have a colon in front of the digits.
What I have so far is the following:

**STRING:**

```
1547 blabla bla 2458 blablabla bla:1548 blabla 8547 blablabla
```

**REGEX:**

```
\d{4} .*?(?=\d{4})
```

This results in the following:

```
1547 blabla bla   
2458 blablabla bla:  
1548 blabla
```

The desired outcome however is:

```
1547 blabla bla   
2458 blablabla bla:1548 blabla  
8547 blablabla
```

I tried the following but without success:

```
(?<!:)\d{4} .*?(?=\d{4})
```

https://regex101.com/r/Zw6Wpw/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
\b\d{4}\b.*?(?=[^:]\d{4}\b|$)
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zw6Wpw/2)

**RegEx Explained**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `\d{4}`: Match 4 digits
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters (lazy match)
- `(?=[^:]\d{4}\b|$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have non-colon character and 4 digits word ahead of or there is end of line position

Alternatively you may use this regex also with a nested negative lookbehind:

```
\b\d{4}\b.*?(?=(?<!:)\d{4}\b|$)
```